# custom form using react

Tags: reactjs, forms

so basically i have created this:

[image: images]

so what i've done here is that i got data from this website https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ using api and i stored them in useState and i mapped over them and posted an image based on the thumbnail and the text below it. what i want now is to be able to add any image to the posts when i add the url,thumbnail url and text.

i thought about doing it like in form but didn't know how to take the data in the input field to the div that will be created , of course i can do it in other ways but i'm actually stuck here and don't know what to do:

my code so far:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Form from '../form/form';

const Data = () => {

    const [photo,setPhoto] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(
            result => {
                setPhoto(result.data)
            }
        )
    },[])

    const [Url,setUrl] = useState()
    const[photoId,setPhotoId] = useState()

    const showPicture = (url,id) => {
        setUrl(url)
        setPhotoId(id)
    }


    const handleDelete = id => {
        setUrl(null);
        setPhoto(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.id !== id));
      };




    return(
        <div>
            <div><img src={Url} onClick={() => handleDelete(photoId)}></img></div>
            <div>Posts</div>
            {/* <p>enter album Id to see the magic</p><input type="text" value={albumId} onChange={e => setAlbumId(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Fetch Album</button> */}
            <div className="container">
            <div>{photo.slice(0,3).map(p => 
                 <div key={p.id}>
                    <img src={p.thumbnailUrl} thumbnailUrl={p.thumbnailUrl} onClick={() => showPicture(p.url,p.id)}></img>
                        <div>{p.title}</div>
                </div>
            )}</div>
            </div>  
        </div>

    )
}

export default Data;
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_forms.asp

Comment: Can u plz elaborate your prblm more. What actually you want to do

Comment: @AdityaShende so basically you can see that i'm getting data from api, what i want is to make a form that will take thumbnail url, url, and title of any image on the internet and when i submit it will appear with the other posts up top